# Triple Integral with difficult limits.

Tags: calculus

I don't understand how to count integral bounds from the inequality.

$$\iiint\limits_{V}(x-2)dV $$ where

$$V=\left\{(x, y, z):\frac{(x-2)^2}{9}+\frac{(y+3)^2}{25}+\frac{(z+1)^2}{16} < 1\right\}$$

Comment: Hint: $V$ is symmetric about $x=2$.

Answer (score 6):

As @JohnMa hinted, we infer from the symmetry about $x-2=0$ that the volume integral is zero.  If one wishes to forgo using the symmetry argument, then we can proceed to evaluate the volume integral directly.

---

**METHOD 1:**

We use Cartesian coordinates and take as the inner integral, the integration over $x$ and write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{2-3\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2}}^{2-3\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2}} (x-2)\,dx&=\int_{-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2}}^{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2}}9x\,dx\\\\
&=\frac92 \left.x^2\right|_{-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2}}^{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2}}\\\\
&=\frac92\left(1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2\right)\\\\
&-\frac92\left(1-\left(\frac{y+3}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z+1}{4}\right)^2\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Thus, the volume integral is zero as expected!

---

**METHOD 2:**

We first change variables with

$$\frac{x-2}{3}=u$$

$$\frac{y+3}{5}=v$$

$$\frac{z+1}{4}=w$$

The Jacobian for the transformation is trivially $60$.  Thus,

$$\int_V (x-2) dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{V'}(3u)\,60du\,dv\,dw$$

where $V'$ is the spherical region defined by $u^2+v^2+w^2\le1$.  Now, we change coordinates again, this time using a spherical coordinate system with

$$\begin{align}
u&=R\sin t\,\cos s\\\\
v&=R\sin t\,\sin s\\\\
w&=R\cos t
\end{align}$$

The Jacobian here is $R^2\,\sin t$ and thus

$$\begin{align}
\int_{V'}(3u)\,60du\,dv\,dw&=180\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}R \sin t\cos s R^2 \sin t dR\, dt\,ds\\\\
&=\frac{45\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos s\,ds\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

as expected again!!

Comment: @anichka Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.